# Why my property "cursor:progress" won't display correctly during the Js transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The idea is to have a transition from the home page and the about page with a centered logo animation, very simple. During the animation, I would need my cursor set to `cursor: progress` and visible

[image]

At this stage, I get the problem is with the declaration of my .load-container. My cursor is still displaying the `cursor: pointer;` of my button

[image]

When I remove that rule:

```
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 100;
pointer-events: none;
```

I can see my `cursor: progress` but unfortunately the transition is positioning below and the button is visible.

**Anybody out there know how to fix this in css or Js? 
have a look at my code pen project:**

https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg

Answer (score 0):

```
pointer-events: none;
```

will prevent the pointer being changed by CSS rules on that element so you can either remove that rule or move the pointer rule to a parent element

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events for more info :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem is when I remove ```pointer:events: none; ``` from my ```.load-container``` I`m not able to click anymore on my button. The fastest way is to tested  [here](https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg)

Comment: what button are you not able to click on? The demo you've linked to seems to work correctly (I'm able to navigate to the about page and back again)

Comment: yes sure, but when If I add ```pointer-events: none;``` to my CSS  here how it looks, I updated the codepen right [now](https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg). I would need that during the black transition sliding  I have a cursor indicating progress  e.g. ```cursor:progress```

Comment: Ahh I see, try moving pointer-events:none to .loading-screen. Alternatively, just remove pointer-events: none unless there is a reason you need it?

Comment: unfortunately if I move pointer-events to .loading-screen I still have the issue. If I add ```pointer-events: none;``` I'm able to click on the button but my cursor: progress won`t display. You could easily test in my codepen to have more clear the situation

Comment: this is how it should look my cursor during my transition. [have a look](https://pasteboard.co/J9GvWzX.gif)

Comment: Okay, I've checked and the issue you're having is that your load-container element is always on top of your page. That's why you've had to use `pointer-events:none`. I think what you need to do is fix the transitions so that load-container isn't on-screen.

Comment: Thanks richp. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: sorry, I've not used barba before so I'd suggest checking their docs or posting a new question to get help with that :)

Comment: Actually I almost fix this on Js adding this  ```$(".animate-this").on("click" ,function() {
     $('.load-container').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
});```  but now I have to reset the function